# How to except button from being filtered?

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade

In my code, there's table and index=text element that filter the search result. It works well, If user types 'foo', then table row that has 'foo' remains and other rows are being hidden with keyup. 
But the thing is, If I search 'edit' or 'delete', since it's also in the table row, the filter ain't works. How do I except those buttons from filter?

I try giving id or class to each table data to separate button and other rows, but if I do that results are text but not table(looks bad).

'''html

```
<tbody id="EL">
    @foreach($detail as $event)
    <tr>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->id }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->your_name }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->email }}</td>
        <td class="td"><a href="{{ route('participants.create', $event->id) }}"
            data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="
                {{ $event->participants->pluck('date', 'name') }}<br>
            "> {{ $event->title }} </a></td>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->location }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->description }}</td>
        <td class="td">{{ $event->date }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{ route('events.edit', $event) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->id) }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

'''

'''javascript

```
function filterItem(self){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Input").on("keyup", function(){
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            // $("#EL tr").filter(function() {
            $("#EL td").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

'''

filter works even though I search for edit or delete. If there's edit or delete in content of row, it should remain in result.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this using the `has()` to check it the current `<td>` has a `<button>` element can do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Input").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    let x = $("table td").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).has('button').length > 0 ? true : $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id="Input" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Button</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Delete</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btn">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment : ) But if I search for 'delete' in your code, there's still result : ( What I want to do is like if 'Jill smith' is 'Jill delete', and I search for 'delete', only 1st row is remain in result.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but when I type 'delete', the result I want to display is just { Jill Delete 50 [Delete] } this row. this code displays Delete [Delete] [Delete] ; (